# Add/remove unordered lists based on screen resolution with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a section where I need to show my content in 1 to 4 columns based on the screen resolution. For example, if the resolution is 320 pixels wide, it should only display one ul and with a resolution of 1200 pixels wide, it should display four columns.

The problem is the content I have inside it, since I have to redistribute content equally in each visible column. The HTML I have looks something like this:

```
<ul class="projectsList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="projectsList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="projectsList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="projectsList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS looks something like this:

```
.projectsList{
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.projectsList li{
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #CCC;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.mediaScreen{
    width: 1024px)
```

And here's the code I have so far:

```
var mediaScreen = $('.mediaScreen').css('width');
var targetColumns;
var movingMosaics;
var wrapper = $(".projectsList");
var mosaic = $(".projectsList li");
var callback = false;

function adjustProjects(){
    if(mediaScreen == '1401px'){
        targetColumns = 4;
    }else if(mediaScreen == '1024px' || mediaScreen == '800px'){
        targetColumns = 3;
    }else if(mediaScreen == '600px'){
        targetColumns = 2;
    }else if(mediaScreen == '320px'){
        targetColumns = 1;
    }

    //When want columns to collapse
    if (wrapper.not('.empty').length > targetColumns){
        for (var i = $targetCols; i < $currentCols; i++){
            movingMosaics = wrapper.eq(i).find('li').addClass('moving');
            if(mosaicsToMove == wrapper.eq(i).find('.moving').length){
                callback = true;
                wrapper.eq(i).addClass('empty');
            }
        }

        if (callback == true){
           for(var j=0; j<movingMosaics.length; j++){
               for(var i=0; i<$targetCols; i++){
                   if(!wrapper.eq(i).hasClass("last")){
                       wrapper.eq(i).append(movingMosaics.eq(0))
                       movingMosaics.eq(j).removeClass('moving')
                       $(".last").removeClass("last");
                       wrapper.eq(1).addClass("last");
                       break;
                   };
               };
           };
        }

    //When want columns to expand
    }else if(wrapper.not('.empty').length < targetColumns){
        var totalIemsToMove = wrapper.find('li').length/targetColumns;
        var itemsPerCol = wrapper.find('li').length / wrapper.not('.empty').length;
        var itemsPerColToMove = itemsPerCol - totalIemsToMove;
        var indexItems = itemsPerCol - itemsPerColToMove;

        for(var i = 0; i< wrapper.not('.empty').length; i++){
            for (var j = indexItems; j <= itemsPerCol; j++){
                movingMosaics = wrapper.eq(i).find(' li').eq(j).addClass('reassign');
                if(totalIemsToMove == $('.reassign').length){
                    callback = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (callback== true){
            for (var j = wrapper.not('.empty').length; j < targetColumns; j++){
                for (var i = 0; i < movingMosaics.length*2; i++){
                    wrapper.eq(j).append(movingMosaics.eq(i));
                        movingMosaics.eq(j).removeClass('reassign');
                    }
                    if($('.reassign').length == 0){
                           wrapper.eq(j).removeClass('empty');
                    }
                }
            }
            callback == false;
        }
    }
```

The script has some issues; it partially works. So basically if I have 12 elements I have to move them equally to the number of visible "uls". For four visible columns there must be three elements, for three visible columns there must be four elements in each column and so on... The mediaScreen class changes based on the media query resolution.

I think that I am making the script very complicated, and I have erased everything and started all over again a few times already without any luck. What would be a way to solve this problem?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you're moving elements from on column to another if the number of columns are different. Does this mean the order of the elements don't matter?

Comment: It would be the best if the order of the elements could be respected always, but I'm more concerned right now if it works, Amin.

Comment: So something like this wouldn't be good because the orders are mixed up http://jsfiddle.net/ESVHS/1/

Comment: I'm more than glad to hear a suggestion even if the orders are mixed, so don't worry too much about that :)

Comment: I thought that the easiest way to solve that problem was to clear the float to certain columns when the resolution gets smaller. The problem there was when I have space for only 3 inline columns. I would end up with 1 big column and 2 small columns.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any JavaScript code to make your columns disappear based on screen size. Use CSS:

#### HTML

```
<ul class="projectsList">
    <li>main1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="projectsList hide-phone">
    <li>phone1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="projectsList hide-tablet">
    <li>tablet1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="projectsList hide-desktop">
    <li>desktop1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.projectsList {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.projectsList li {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #CCC;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    list-style: none;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .hide-desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .hide-desktop {
        display: none;
    }
    .hide-tablet {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
    .hide-desktop {
        display: none;
    }
    .hide-tablet {
        display: none;
    }
    .hide-phone {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Check out my jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/eLFKm/.

Comment: Yes, that's basically the idea to hide columns but the only problem is that the elements inside the hidden columns are invisible too. I need to make all the elements visible always no matter if there is only 1 or 4 columns.

Comment: I'm also using media queries on my style. That's how I keep track of the resolution on my screen.
I change the .mediaScreen class width on each resolution, for example:
@media (max-width: 320px) {.mediaScreen{width:320px}}